# Destructuring statement in chrome/chromium 44 not being recognised

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, chromium, destructuring

As far as I know, this is valid EcmaScript6:

```
let obj = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}; 
let {foo, bar} = obj; // <- Syntax error here
```

Firefox runs this code just fine, but both Google Chrome and Chromium give me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I know in firefox, scripts tags have to be flagged with "version=1.7" in the type attribute for this to work, but in Google Chrome this results in the script getting ignored. A normal script tag gives this error.

Does this mean this feature is not implemented in Google Chrome? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

That's right. Currently, it isn't supported yet.

https://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/destructuring_assignment

Comment: Right, so only on Firefox for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Setzer22 but that doesn't mean you can't use it. Look into a transpiler like [babel.js](http://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Although Chrome doesn't support some new features of ES6 (check this [table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to see what is already supported on different browsers), you can use a polyfill/plugins to enable certain features on Chrome. You can find polyfill and [plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) on [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Just read through the plugins documentation and implement the ones you want.